# Paperclip dosnt save attachments if password has attr_accessor

Tags: paperclip, attachment

My project:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         attr_accessor :password 
         attr_accessible :email,
           :password, 
           :password_confirmation, 
           :first_name, 
           :last_name, 
           :birth_date, 
           :residence, 
           :user_role, 
           :show_email,
           :avatar

         as_attached_file :avatar, 
         :default_url => '/images/system/user_avatars/default/default_avatar.png',
         :url => "/public/images/system/user_avatars/:id_:style.:extension",
         :path => "/public/system/user_avatars/:id_:style.:extension"

         def update_profile(user_id, params) #params has :category and :user params
            @user = User.find(user_id)
            @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            return params[:category]
         end
    end
```

So, from my controller i call this method and i get no error. Paperclip shows attachment saved. The database is updated, but the image file is not saved. I have an registration made from scratch, so that's why i have the "attr_accessor :password"

I checked:

- Have :multipart => true in form
- Have attr_accessible :avatar in user model

Can any one give me some lead, cos i cant figure, why paperclip dosnt save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Set `attr_accessible :avatar_file_name` as well, and you also need a **paperclip.rb initializer**:

```
require "paperclip"  
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/ImageMagick"
```

And, of course, have ImageMagick installed.